# How to create new sub folder with for loop when have range condition?

Tags: python

Now I'm try to Automation create new directory folder with python everyday.I need to create new fix sub folder by my list.  Like this:

[image]

This's my script:

```
import os
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
d1 = today.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
#Ie Source Path
ie = ["G:/01-FIN & ACC-Confidential/Inbound/IE-Direct/",
"G:/02-BDSM (ห้ามย้ายเด็ดขาด)-Confidential/Inbound/IE-Direct/",
"G:/03-BSC-Confidential/Inbound/IE-Direct/",
"G:/04-CLD-Confidential/Inbound/IE-Direct/",
"G:/05-COMPLIANCE-Confidential/Inbound/IE-Direct/",
"G:/06-CRD-Confidential/Inbound/IE-Direct/",

# define the access rights
access_rights = 0o755

team = ["ACCOUNTING","BDSM","BSC","CLD","COMPLIANCE","CRD","HR","IT","MGT","MKT","OPS","COPORATE SALES","TELESALES","PASSAPORN","FRAUD","LEGAL","INS","BIQM",]

for i,j in ie+team:
    os.mkdir(i+str(d1)+"/"+j)
```

Please tell me how to create sub-directories in the folders with already created with current program.

Comment: What's the problem with this script?

Comment: You want to create sub-directories in the folders you have already created with the current program?

Comment: Yes.I need to create sub-directories in the folders you have already created with the current program.

Comment: The code currently in your question couldn't possibly work, so saying "with already created with current program" isn't helpful. Exactly what folder structure are you trying to create?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code but it says too many values to unpack, then i modified your code to create 6 directories and then again create 3 sub-directories in those 6 directories.

```
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
d1 = today.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
#Ie Source Path
ie = ["D:/t/",
"D:/t/",
"D:/t/",
"D:/t/",
"D:/t/",
"D:/t/"]

# define the access rights
access_rights = "0o755"

team = ["ACCOUNTING","BM","BSC","CLD","COMPLIANCE","CRD"]//actual 6 directories 
new_subs=["1","2","3"] //names of 3 subdirectories

os.mkdir(ie[0]+str(d1))//main directory named as today's date

for i in range(0,6):
    os.mkdir(ie[i]+str(d1)+"/"+team[i])
    for j in range(len(new_subs)):
        os.mkdir(ie[i]+str(d1)+"/"+team[i]+"/"+new_subs[j])
```

Give a comment if their are any doubts about the code